# Is there a summation method where the divergent series $S = U_0+U_1+U_2+\dots$ converges to a finite value?

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinite-sequences

Consider the function
$$
M(v) = \frac{m_0}{\sqrt{1 - \left(\frac{v}{c}\right)^2}},
$$ where $v \in \left]-c;c\right[$, $m_0\in\mathbb{R}^{*+}$, and $c=3\cdot10^8$.

- Let $(U_n)$ be a sequence with general term
  $$
  U_n = M\left(c-\frac{1}{n+2}\right)-M\left(c-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)\label{1}\tag{$U$}
  $$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$,
- let the sequence its partial sums $S_n$ be defined as $S_n = U_0+U_1+U_2+\ldots+U_n$, and finally
- let $S$ be the sum of the series defined by \eqref{1}, i.e. $S = U_0+U_1+U_2+\ldots$

The series $S = U_0+U_1+U_2+\ldots=+\infty$ diverges to infinity
and is not Cesàro summable, i.e. it does not converge in the sense of Cesàro, just like the series $1+2+3+\ldots=+\infty$ (for more details, please refer to the [Wikipedia entry on Cesàro summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation)).

On the other hand, the divergent series $1+2+3+\dots$ can be summed by using the zeta regularization summation method to $-1/12$ (for more details, please refer to the [related Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF)).

**Questions**:

- Is there a summation method where the divergent series $S = U_0+U_1+U_2+\ldots$ converges to a finite value?
- Is there a summation method where the divergent series $S = U_0+U_1+U_2+\ldots$ converges to a finite value equal to $m_0$?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Math.SE: are you basically asking if there is a summation method which can be used to sum a series which is equivalent to the relativistic mass at the velocity $v=c$ to its rest value $m_0$, aren't you?

Comment: Yes because: For $v=c$, we have $M(c)=\lim_{v \to c-} M(v)$.

I let $x+2=1/(c-v)$, so $v=c-1/(x+2)$. Therefore:

$M(c)=\lim_{v \to c-} M(v)=\lim_{{x \to +\infty}}M(c-1/(x+2))$.

 So we have: $M(c)=\lim_{v \to c-} M(v)=\lim_{{x \to +\infty}}M(c-1/(x+2))=\lim_{{n\to +\infty}}M(c-1/(n+2))$. and $S_n=M(c-1/(n+2)$ wih $ U_n=S_n-S_{n-1}$ so $M(c)=S$

Comment: What can work here is to use the formula given in section 3 "Expression in terms of the partial sum" of  [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4619793/760992).

Comment: sorry I dont speak english , I use traductor. I meant to ask if you could answer the questions of this problem. "Section 3" refers to a specific section or part of the problem. Can you provide more context or clarify what "Section 3" refers to in your original question?

Comment: @ Saibal mitra I see, tnk you

Comment: $$
\begin{align}
& v \in ]-c;c[ \\ {} \\
& v \in \left]-c;c\right[
\end{align}
$$
When one notices the conspicuous typographical differences between the two lines above, it doesn't take long to realize what's happening: In the first line, it's treating the minus sign as a binary rather than unary operation symbol, hence the amount of space to its left and right, and it's treating the square brace before the minus sign like a right delimiter rather than a left delimiter, so it treats in the member-of symbol like a unary rather than binary operation symbol, hence$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$the lack of space to its right. I corrected this by inserting `\left` and `\right`, yielding the second line above.

Comment: It seems nearly all LaTeX users are unaware that Knuth designed TeX precisely in order to make attention to this kind of detail possible. Little details like this that most people don't notice are the reason why they do notice that one font looks much better than another.

Comment: I apologize, I'm using ChatGPT to write the formulas in LaTeX code.

Answer (score 4):

I strongly caution against ascribing any physics meaning to the following manipulations, but of course you can just separate off the divergent part of $M$ and define it via $\zeta $-function regularization. Define
$$
M_d (n) = m_0 \sqrt{\frac{c}{2}} \sqrt{n}
$$
and write
$$
U_n = \left[ M\left( c-\frac{1}{n+2} \right) - M_d (n+2) - M\left( c-\frac{1}{n+1} \right) + M_d (n+1)\right] \\ + [M_d (n+2)] - [M_d (n+1)]
$$
and sum the 3 square brackets separately. Note that the combination of the first two terms in the first square brackets vanishes for $n\rightarrow \infty $, and therefore, since the sum over the first square brackets telescopes, that sum reduces to
$$
S^{(1)} = -M(c-1) + M_d (1)
$$
The sum over the second square brackets is
$$
S^{(2)} = m_0 \sqrt{\frac{c}{2} } \sum_{n=2}^{\infty } \sqrt{n}
= m_0 \sqrt{\frac{c}{2} } \left( \zeta \left(-\frac{1}{2} \right) - 1 \right)
$$
and analogously for the third square brackets
$$
S^{(3)} = m_0 \sqrt{\frac{c}{2} } \ \zeta \left(-\frac{1}{2} \right)
$$
so the entire sum reduces to the finite value
\begin{align}
S & = S^{(1)} + S^{(2)} - S^{(3)} \\[8pt]
& = -M(c-1) + M_d (1) - m_0 \sqrt{\frac{c}{2} } \\[8pt]
& =-M(c-1)
\end{align}
If you want to achieve some other value, you can always supplement this with more Eilenberg–Mazur swindles.