# Is there a summation method where the divergent series $S = U_0+U_1+U_2+\dots$ converges to a finite value(V2)?

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinite-sequences

I have a question regarding this question here.

[is-there-a-summation-method-where-the-divergent-series](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/449868/is-there-a-summation-method-where-the-divergent-series-s-u-0u-1u-2-dots-c)

if I set $ x+2=c/c-v$ , will I have
$U_n = M\left(c-\frac{c}{n+2}\right)-M\left(c-\frac{c}{n+1}\right), \label{1}\tag{$U$} $

and will $M(c)=M(c-1)$, or  $M(c)=-M(c-c)=-M(0)=-m_0$?

Comment: What question?  Your link just tries to go to the general list https://mathoverflow.net/questions.

Comment: Sorry, it's okay now

Answer (score 2):

Are the $U_n$ supposed to have a physical meaning or is this a purely mathematical exercises? if we directly interpret:

$$ U_n = M\left(c-\frac{1}{n+2}\right)-M\left(c-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)\label{2}\tag{$U$} = \frac{m_0}{\sqrt{1 - 1 + \frac{2}{c(n+2)} - \frac{1}{c^2(n+2)^2}}} -  \frac{m_0}{\sqrt{1 - 1 + \frac{2}{c(n+1)} - \frac{1}{c^2(n+1)^2}}} 
 = m_0 \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{2}{c(n+2)} - \frac{1}{c^2(n+2)^2}}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{2}{c(n+1)} - \frac{1}{c^2(n+1)^2}}}  \right) = m_0 c \left( \frac{n+2}{\sqrt{2c(n+2) -1 }} - \frac{n+1}{\sqrt{2c(n+1)-1}}  \right) =   $$

It's not clear to me how to assign units to the last object. It seems like the $n$ and $1$ and $2$ need to be given units for the whole thing to remain physical with dimensional analysis.

Anyways... I believe that $U_n = O(n^{-\frac{1}{2}}) $  so one could use the Euler Maclaurin formula on this and see if that suggests a constant term in its asymptotic expansion. This will be very tedious and I'll get around to it later (unless someone beats me to it :) )

Comment: Thank you very much. It would be a physically sound theory formulated mathematically in that case. Have you considered that $x+2=\frac{1}{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}$?

Comment: im sorry but your comment doesn't make sense to me. What does " It would be a physically sound theory formulated mathematically in that case" mean? do you mean to say "if we gave n,1,2 appropriate units then the expression is physically sound?"

Comment: Sorry i edit question